# Dedicated server setup error "not supported" what am i missing here

Tags: magento-1.9, installation

http://66.147.230.65/~freedomperform/  trying to install magento page simply states not supported?

Comment: Contact server provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have gathered,

> The "Not Supported" message will occur when using the "CGI" handler
>   with Apache Mod_Userdir. You will need to use another handler (e.g.
>   suphp) if you want to utilize Apache Mod_Userdir.

Documentation on selecting PHP handlers https://confluence2.cpanel.net/display/EA/PHP+Handlers

Read about mod_userdir: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_userdir.html

Comment: hmm so easy apache4 i reckon. So i need to remove the cgi modules and install suphp?

Comment: Check your easyApache profile settings.  You can learn about easy apache here: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Introduction+to+EasyApache